# How do I use NumberDecimal()

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to store currency data in MongoDB using `NumberDecimal()` as per the documentation suggests, however, I'm getting `ReferenceError: NumberDecimal is not defined`. I'm running `db version v4.2.2` and `MongoDB shell version v4.2.2` within Nodejs.

What am I missing here? Is this an import problem.

```
const result = await client
  .db('PurchaseOrders')
  .collection('purchaseOrders')
  .updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectId(_id) },
    {
      $set: { data: NumberDecimal('1.02') }
    },
    {
      upsert: true
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumberDecimal exists in the `mongo` shell. It does not exist in nodejs (or in vanilla js).

From vanilla js you should be able to use extended json syntax:

```
const result = await client
  .db('PurchaseOrders')
  .collection('purchaseOrders')
  .updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectId(_id) },
    {
      $set: { data: {'$numberDecimal':'1.02'} }
    },
    {
      upsert: true
    }
  );
```

Comment: If data was an object. Would you simply make use `data.total = Number(data.total)`?

Comment: Number is a float, per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number. You may be able to use BigInt for something (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) but you'd need to convert it to a string for data interchange purposes anyway.